# Save File Thumbnail as image in windows runtime

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to get Thumbnail of files stored in Videos folder and save them as image in my local folder . 
here is my code to get files .

```
var v = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
foreach (var file in v)
{
    var thumb = await file.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.SingleItem);
    BitmapImage Img = new BitmapImage();
    Img.SetSource(thumb);
    await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("VideoThumb");
    var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
              "VideoThumb\\" + file.Name, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
    var fs = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    //I don't know how to save thumbnail on this file !
}
```

my project is a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime C# app .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things you need to handle:

- you don't need *BitmapImage*, as thumbnail provides a stream which you can write directly to file,
- you are not handling the case when create file method fails (file exists),
- create folder method will throw exception as the folder is created (or already exists) with the first file in foreach. Rather than that, create/open folder outside foreach,
- also creating image with `file.Name` is not a good idea, hence those are videos and their extension will likely be *mp4/mpg/other* not *jpg/png/other*,
- remember to add *capabilities* in *packageappx.manifest* file.

I think the below code should do the job:

```cs
private async Task SaveViedoThumbnails()
{
    IBuffer buf;
    StorageFolder videoFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("VideoThumb", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer inputBuffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(1024);

    var v = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in v)
    {
        var thumb = await file.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.SingleItem);
        var imageFile = await videoFolder.CreateFileAsync(file.DisplayName + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var destFileStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            while ((buf = (await thumb.ReadAsync(inputBuffer, inputBuffer.Capacity, Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.None))).Length > 0)
                await destFileStream.WriteAsync(buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm new in Windows Runtime . Before that I working on Silverlight and I don't know many things here . really thanks for your help . could you please tell me how can I convert this files to a uri or a bit map Image to show ?

Comment: @AliNGame As for Uri I would suggest to read [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx) and [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322.aspx). As for setting image from StorageFile, you will find some posts on SO.

Comment: hmmmmmm thanks ;) ms-appdata:///local/...
Thanks again . you help me so much