# Cannot set the thumbnail of a video windows phone 8.1(RT)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating a windows phone 8.1(RT) application. I have videos in my LocalStorage and I'm trying to display the thumbnail for them.
Code:
thumbnailToImage Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            BitmapImage bp = new BitmapImage();
            try
            {
                bp.SetSource((StorageItemThumbnail)value);
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Came in Catch");
                Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/play.png");
                bp.UriSource = uri;
            }
            return bp;
        }
```

Code in the file setting the thumbnail:

```
 try
   {
      thumb = await i.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.VideosView);
   }
   catch
   {                             
     Debug.WriteLine("Failed to get the thumbnail of the video");
     thumb = null;
   }
```

Note: Instead of the videosView I've tried them all but none seems to work. I always end up in the catch block of the converter and end up displaying a default icon.And also I'm using the same approach for images which is working perfectly.
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28374646/2681948)?

Comment: @Romasz : Thanks for the reply. But I'm still not able to retrieve the thumbnail for a video. I was wondering do we have to use a buffer of its alright if we just use a storageItemThumbnail and use a converter to convert into bitmap image and bind that to the xaml?

Comment: Is it possible that you can share the sample project with the problem?