# How to take a snapshot with MediaElement in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP project want to take a snapshot from Mediaelement while playing the video.

Does anyone know any useful links or how to tackle this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirement, you could realize it with [`Custom video effects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects). Because you could get per frame in [`ProcessFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Effects.IBasicVideoEffect#Windows_Media_Effects_IBasicVideoEffect_ProcessFrame_Windows_Media_Effects_ProcessVideoFrameContext_) method. And you could use a static property to store current frame and pass it to your image control. The following is [`RExampleVidoEffect`](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/GetSnapShotFormMediaElement908.git) class.

```
public sealed class RExampleVidoEffect : IBasicVideoEffect
{

    private static SoftwareBitmap Snap;
    public void SetEncodingProperties(VideoEncodingProperties encodingProperties, IDirect3DDevice device)
    {

    }

    public void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context)
    {
        var inputFrameBitmap = context.InputFrame.SoftwareBitmap;
        Snap = inputFrameBitmap;
    }

    public static SoftwareBitmap GetSnapShot()
    {
        return Snap;
    }
    public void Close(MediaEffectClosedReason reason)
    {

    }

    public void DiscardQueuedFrames()
    {

    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<VideoEncodingProperties> SupportedEncodingProperties
    {
        get { return new List<VideoEncodingProperties>(); }
    }
    public MediaMemoryTypes SupportedMemoryTypes
    {
        get { return MediaMemoryTypes.Cpu; }
    }

    public bool TimeIndependent
    {
        get { return true; }
    }



    public void SetProperties(IPropertySet configuration)
    {

    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private async void VideoPlayer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var videoFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("big_buck_bunny.mp4");  
    MediaClip clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(videoFile);

    var videoEffectDefinition = new VideoEffectDefinition(typeof(RExampleVidoEffect).FullName);
    clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(videoEffectDefinition);

    MediaComposition compositor = new MediaComposition();
    compositor.Clips.Add(clip);

    this.VideoPlayer.SetMediaStreamSource(compositor.GenerateMediaStreamSource());

}


private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bitmap = RExampleVidoEffect.GetSnapShot();

    if (bitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8 ||
         bitmap.BitmapAlphaMode == BitmapAlphaMode.Straight)
    {
        bitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(bitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
    }
    var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
    await source.SetBitmapAsync(bitmap);
    img.Source = source;
}
```

**Effect**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to search through online resource but most of them are using the storage file thumbnail method!
[reference links 1]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372214/save-file-thumbnail-as-image-in-windows-runtime)
[reference links 2]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667235/how-to-get-thumbnail-from-a-video-in-windows-store-app)
they didn't provide suffice for me to get snapshot while in playing mode! Thanks you for your answer!